# How do i separate JavaScript View/Logic code properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller, templates

I receive JSON objects from a websocket with update/create/delete flags. Based on this information, I either update, create or delete HTML elements and bind callbacks. This can affect multiple HTML elements.

My current approach was to put everything into specific objects which handle HTML generation via jquery e.g.:

```
$.("<table>").addChild($("<tr>")).addClass('test')
```

and bind event listeners. But with the addition of more and more code it got really messy and now im looking for a proper way to seperate the code.

Are there any ideas on how to do this properly? Frameworks? Maybe jQuery Templates (which still leaves me in the dark on how add callbacks cleanly)?

Comment: have you try to create custom events?

Comment: Never heard of them, Ive just looked them up and I dont think that would help in seperating the view/logic code. If you have an idea on how to use these, please explain :)

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495680/can-anyone-suggest-design-pattern-to-separate-business-logic-and-presentation-lo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case I can recommend you to have a look at [Knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/) , [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) or [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/).

Comment: Thank you, I've taken a look at both Knockoutjs and AngularJS and I understand the way AngularJS does things better.

Answer (score 4):

Look up the MVVM framework. This is exactly what you're needing as your JavaScript is getting increasingly more complex. It seperates your needs for concern between your Presentation code (html) and Presentation Logic (JavaSript)

[Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) is a really good library to get you started, I recommend going through the tutorials to get you started on it.

Quick example:

**HelloWorld.html**

```
<div data-bind="value: helloWorldVariable"></div>
<input type="button" data-bind="click: helloWorld" />
```

**page.js:**

```
var ViewModel = {
   helloWorldVariable: ko.observable('test'),
   helloWorld: function() {
       this.helloWorldVariable('clicked!');
   }
}

// Bind viewmodel
```

When the button is clicked, the div will automatically display "clicked". This, obviously, can be used when retrieving information from the server via AJAX requests and you don't have to rely on control IDs / CSS classes. They can change at any time, and your code is still relevant.

Answer (score 0):

To render html you can use [Handlerbars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/) it is very mature and have lots of documentation

For event binding I recommend you to use [jQuery delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) on the parent object that don't had deleted with the ajax update. This way you only need to reassign events on every request

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org). It's a very popular and flexible MVC-ish set up for JS browser apps. The code is hosted on [github](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone).

Answer (score 0):

[Knockout JS](http://knockoutjs.com/) might be worth a look, it separates the data model from the view model and takes care of the dependencies between them.